# same ng-model to display two different parameters on two different input boxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form in which the data is loaded in a dropdown list which has `ng-model="placeid"`, Now when the user selects the data from the first ng-model I want it to display the parameter place.lat of the chosen option in the input box.
So When the user selects the value from the list below

```
<select class="form-group" ng-model="placeID" required>
    <option size=50 value="" disabled selected>Select a place</option>
    <option ng-repeat="place in places.places" value="{{place.placeID}}">{{place.name}}</option>
</select>
```

The latitude parameter should be display in the box below:

```
<input ng-model="placeID" type="text" name="q" size="31" placeholder="{{place.name}}" maxlength="255">
```

In order to make it clear, the purpose of what I am doing is that in drop down there is a form which user can submit and input is part of the google map search.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a property to your scope that stores the currently selected place and bind the select and the input to that property. So your controller would like something like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('placeCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.places = [
        {
            placeID: 1,
            name: 'Place 1',
            lat: 123,
            long: 321
        },
        {
            placeID: 2,
            name: 'Place 2',
            lat: 456,
            long: 654
        },
        {
            placeID: 3,
            name: 'Place 3',
            lat: 789,
            long: 987
        }
    ];

    $scope.selectedPlace = $scope.places[1];
});
```

The HTML page would look like this:

```
<div ng-controller="placeCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedPlace" ng-options="place.name for place in places">
    </select>
    <br />
    <input ng-model="selectedPlace.placeID" type="text"></input>
    <input ng-model="selectedPlace.lat" type="text"></input>
    <input ng-model="selectedPlace.long" type="text"></input>
</div>
```

Here is an example:  [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/9z65T/13/)

Comment: It does not work for me, secondly, The data in the select tag had  a value="placeID" The reason that is there because I am passing the value to be posted, and with the input it is just front end as the latitude and longitude that I need to be displayed in input box needs to be passed on to a map to display where the location is.

Comment: I think you are going to have trouble trying to set the value property to the placeID and also bind the select element to the object that is selected.  If possible I think your best option is to create a input box for the placeID that gets updated when the user changes the selection in the select tag.  You could even make the input that has the placeID hidden if you do not want the user to see it.  I updated my answer and the jsfiddle example to do that.